# sed command working only when no outfile is written

Tags: shell-script, centos, sed, io-redirection

I'd like to change this file eq.txt

```
2018-05-03T18:46:05.050Z 11.8314 44.0586 10 4.3 USGS
2018-05-01T05:16:59.270Z 11.0366 43.2334 10 4.1 USGS
2018-04-26T11:13:20.590Z -5.4109 36.5557 10 4 USGS
2018-04-25T09:48:42.940Z 14.8129 41.9053 10 4.3 USGS
```

to eq-new.txt

```
2018 05 03 18 46 05.050 11.8314 44.0586 10 4.3 USGS
2018 05 01 05 16 59.270 11.0366 43.2334 10 4.1 USGS
2018 04 26 11 13 20.590 -5.4109 36.5557 10 4 USGS
2018 04 25 09 48 42.940 14.8129 41.9053 10 4.3 USGS
```

I change the date and time format using

```bsh
sed -r "s/([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)T([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+)\.000Z/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6.000/g" eq.txt
```

This works as I want.

However as I want to save the result in eq-new.txt, I do

```bsh
sed -r "s/([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)T([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+)\.000Z/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6.000/g" eq.txt > eq-new.txt
```

Unfortunately, the output file is wrong, the date and time format in eq-new.txt is the same as in eq.txt

I've also tried this

```bsh
tmp=$(sed -E "s/([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)T([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+)\.000Z/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6.000/g" tmp.txt)
echo -ne "$tmp" > eq-new.txt
```

No more success !

Nothing that I have found about sed and outfiles works.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Are you sure the command is working when you don't redirect its output to a file? The [answer you have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513369/315749) is right, `\.000Z` matches a literal string containing three zeros; thus, in your sample data, the whole expression matches no line. Compare your command with `sed -r "s/([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)T([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+)Z/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6/g"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern match times ending with `.000` (literal) and no line contains such time. You basically have no matches, so replace is never triggered.